# Assign distinct color to each row in a heat map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using code that can be found at:

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_basic.html

In particular, I want to change the following snippet of code:

```
// Build color scale
var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
   .range(["white", "#69b3a2"])
   .domain([1,100])
```

So it accepts a color as an argument. My intention is to have a separate color for each row of the heat map. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you described here:

> My intention is to have a separate color for each row of the heat map.

I'm assuming that, for each row, you want a different range in the colour scale, going from `"white"` to a specific colour.

If that is correct, you can simply set an array of colours, for instance...

```
var colorArray = d3.schemeCategory10;

//d3.schemeCategory10 is this array of colours:
//["#1f77b4","#ff7f0e","#2ca02c","#d62728","#9467bd","#8c564b","#e377c2","#7f7f7f","#bcbd22","#17becf"]
```

... and then, using the `myVars` array, set the scale range dynamically inside the anonymous function:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
  var thisColor = colorArray[myVars.indexOf(d.variable)]
  myColor.range(["white", thisColor])
  return myColor(d.value)
})
```

Here is the code you linked with that change:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Labels of row and columns
var myGroups = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
var myVars = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9", "v10"]

// Build X scales and axis:
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(myGroups)
  .padding(0.01);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

// Build X scales and axis:
var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain(myVars)
  .padding(0.01);
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var colorArray = d3.schemeCategory10;

// Build color scale
var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1, 100])

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/heatmap_data.csv", function(data) {

  svg.selectAll()
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d.group + ':' + d.variable;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.group)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.variable)
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      var thisColor = colorArray[myVars.indexOf(d.variable)]
      myColor.range(["white", thisColor])
      return myColor(d.value)
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```